# Condition check in where clause based on parameter passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, conditional-statements

The stored procedure I am working on has 2 parameters `@IsApproved (BIT)` and `CustomId (INT)`.

Now in my `WHERE` clause I want to check if `@IsApproved` or not, if it is approved then use `A.[FunctionalId] = @CustomId` else `A.[InstallId] = @CustomId`.

I tried like this, but it throws an error.

```
SELECT 
    AppKeyId, AppName, AppVersion 
FROM 
    dbo.[Application] A
WHERE
    CASE 
       WHEN @IsApproved = 1 THEN A.[FunctionalId] = @CustomId
       ELSE A.[InstallId] = @CustomId
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value, not a boolean result; `THEN A.[FunctionalId] = @CustomId` isn't valid as it's not a scalar value.

Use an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT AppKeyId,
       AppName,
       AppVersion
FROM dbo.Application A
WHERE (@IsApproved = 1 AND A.[FunctionalId] = @CustomId)
   OR (@IsApproved = 0 AND A.[InstallId] = @CustomId);
```